# MetaBox with Editor instead of textarea - html not saved

Tags: metabox, html

I am calling several custom MetaBoxes in my custom post type on Wordpress 4 like this without using a plugin:

```
    array( 
    'label' => __('MyContent',                    myPlugin), 
    'id'    => $prefix.'mycontent',
    'type'  => 'editor'
    ),
```

I can see the wysiwyg editor inside the post and I can also put some text inside which also saves correctly. But when I am using HTML it's not getting saved.

When I save the content and reload the page, the html has gone. What do I have to do, that html gets saved and printed in frontend? And why can't I use html in meta boxes for instance in a "textarea" - is there a reason to only get plain text?

I am using meta_box.php from here:
[GitHub Link](https://github.com/tammyhart/Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes/blob/master/metaboxes/meta_box.php)

thank you!

Comment: Check out the code example http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Comment: Could you show us how you're saving your post meta? Maybe you're stripping the tags at some point.

Comment: Hi Howdy, sorry that it took so long I added the link to the meta_box.php file. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem after many researches,
just comment two lines in meta_box.php file at end.

```
$sanitizer = isset( $field['sanitizer'] ) ? $field['sanitizer'] : 'sanitize_text_field';
```

to

```
//$sanitizer = isset( $field['sanitizer'] ) ? $field['sanitizer'] : 'sanitize_text_field';
```

at line 692 and

```
$new = meta_box_sanitize( $new, $sanitizer );
```

to

```
//$new = meta_box_sanitize( $new, $sanitizer );
```

at line 697

then you can save html or css in metabos editor.